# Sanifflo System

Tags: plumbing

I have the saniflo system. When draining the sink, the water backs up into to the shower. Also the shower drains slow. I have read about Saniflo descaler, my plumber never told me I needed to descale the unit.  Can I use the saniflo descaler to clear to out the slow draining. By just pouring it down the drain?

Comment: I wondered.  https://www.saniflo.com/us/installing-a-toilet/73-saniplus.html

Comment: "*Can I use the saniflo descaler to clear to out the slow draining*"     You can not treat the  symptom until you know what  the problem is that's causing it.  **Have you contacted the plumber or more importantly, Saniflo**. *Water backs up into shower tray or bathtub* is one of the entries in the  trouble shooting section of the installation PDF from the web page Willk linked to.